# Creating dropdown menu in form with mixture of input type text from main table and dropdown options for secondary tables

Tags: php, mysql, forms, drop-down-menu

I am attempting to display data from 3 different database tables in my php form. I want the edit page which is shown below if the InventoryID isn't set to show the current selection of the InventoryID I have selected. All other tables are working through the inventory table to fetch data. For example, type has a table named typeid and the id for that table is 1 and its name for the tyid is Desktop Monitor. The type entry for the inventory table is just the integer 1. It is the same with Descriptor the table name is descriptorid and the id 1 is selected on my main inventory table. I have previously used Left Join to display the tables but I want to know how I can add a dropdown box to the form instead of just the integers for tables like typeid and others. My code below shows the current values of the Inventory table with the integers selected from the secondary tables how can I make just those selections into dropdown boxes while still displaying the current selection and still allow input text for my other selections?

```
    <form action="" method="post">
            <div>
                <?php if ($InventoryID != '') { ?>

                    <input type="hidden" name="InventoryID" value="<?php echo $InventoryID; ?>" />
                    <p>InventoryID: <?php echo $InventoryID; ?></p>
                <?php } ?>

                <strong>Descriptor: *</strong> <input type="text" name="Descriptor"
                    value="<?php echo $descriptor; ?>"/><br/>
                <strong>Type: *</strong> <input type="text" name="Type"
                    value="<?php echo $type; ?>"/><br/>
                    <strong>Serial: *</strong> <input type="text" name="Serial"
                    value="<?php echo $serial; ?>"/><br/>
                    <strong>ServiceTag: *</strong> <input type="text" name="ServiceTag"
                    value="<?php echo $servicetag; ?>"/><br/>
                    <strong>CityTag: *</strong>
                <input name="CityTag" type="text"
                    value="<?php echo $citytag; ?>"/>
                <p>* required</p>
                <input name="submit" type="submit" class="button" value="submit" />
            </div>
            </form>
```